# Android: Searchview opens even onClick of other menu items with different id

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

My SearchView is working fine.. but it is accepting the same behavior when other menuItems are clicked. When I click cart icon then too SearchView is getting called. How do I avoid that?
Here is my code for the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:title="@string/action_cart"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
    </menu>
```

and code for SearchView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem= menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView =(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I want a different behavior when cart icon is clicked but it just does the same action as when clicked on the search icon. I want to limit the SearchView only to the SearchView icon. On the cart Icon i want to perform something else. Please help

Comment: Where do you handle the click event on each separate menu item? Please, include that source code as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to remove:

```
  yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
  yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

from other menu items which are not SearchView